# Git не отслеживает папку исключения .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

В корне проекта находится `.gitignore` и папка `vendor`.

Файл gitignore содержит:

`vendor/` - исключить всю папку `vendor`,

`!vendor/folder` - кроме `folder` в `vendor`.

Git не отслеживает изменения файлов в `vendor` кроме одной - `folder`. Все как и должно быть.

**Проблема**: Git не видит новый файлы, когда я их создаю, только что заметил. Использую *phpstorm* и он обычно предлагает внести новый файл в гит, но не для новых файлов в `folder`, аналогично консоль не видит новые файлы. Решается вопрос напрямую командой `gid add` с ключом `-f`, причём заранее предупреждает, что файл находится в папке, которую исключает (!) один из файлов игнора. Как исправить ситуацию и в чем проблема?

Comment: [It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) `vendor/` -> `vendor/*`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Но так же надо было изменить порядок на такой:
`vendor/*`, потом только `!vendor/folder/`

Comment: *Но так же надо было изменить порядок на такой* У Вас в вопросе и есть такой порядок. Кстати, шаблон `vendor/` эквивалентен `**/vendor/` (все папки `vendor` где бы она не была), а `vendor/*` эквивалентен `/vendor/*` (содержимое папки `vendor`, только той, которая в корне). Возможно Вам нужен `**/vendor/*`.

Comment: Да, я ошибся, порядок по факту был обратный, чем в вопросе - виноват. Мне подошел `vendor/*`, а без `*` не работает.

Comment: @rugleb да, потому что `vendor/` – это «игнорировать эту папку», а `vendor/*` – «игнорировать любой файл или папку в этой папке».